# To show that a 2D nonlinear ODE undergoes a pitchfork bifurcation

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Show that a pitchfork bifurcation occurs when $\mu = 0$ for the system
$$\dot{x} = \mu x + xy + 3y^2$$
$$\dot{y} = -2y + x^2 + 2xy^2$$.

**Attempt at a solution**
If $\dot{x} = 0$ then
$$x = \frac{-3y}{\mu + y}.$$

The Jacobian is
$$J(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}\mu + y & 6y + x\\ 2x + 2y^2 & -2 + 4xy\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that $\det J(0, 0) = -2\mu$ so the $(0, 0)$ fixed point passed from unstable to stable as we pass $\mu = 0$, so we probably have a subcritical pitchfork.

**Related question:** What would you look for in a transcritical or saddle node bifurcation? What's the general procedure for determining the bifurcation type in a 2D system?

Comment: 1. After the pitchfork bifurcation the number of equilibriums changes from 1 to 3. It looks like that you can analyze how many equilibria there are depending on $\mu$. 2. The general procedure is [center manifold reduction](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Center_manifold). If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, [Y. Kuznetsov's book](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/kuznetsov.pdf) provides explicit formulas that allows to recognize codimensione-1 and -2 bifurcations.